# What can be assumed for $\forall m \in K\cap H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we are given groups $K$, $H$ and $G$, such that $H\trianglelefteq G $ and $K \leq G$. Prove that $K\cap H \trianglelefteq G$.

My work:
Let $g \in G$ and $m \in K\cap H$. Since $m \in  H$ and $m \in K$ and $H\trianglelefteq G$, can we assume that for $\forall m \in K\cap H$, $gmg^{-1} \in K\cap H$?

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to show that $K\cap H \unlhd K$? The conclusion as written is not true, in general.

Comment: it is not true.

Comment: And you should not add the discrete math as  a tag.

Comment: The task is to prove that $K\cap H \trianglelefteq G$. Can this be proven, any hints @James ?

Comment: @Franklin: again it is not true.

Comment: Can you give me an example for which this is not true @mesel?

Comment: ok wait let me give you an example.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.

Let $G=S_3\times Z_3$ and $H =S_3\times 1$ then $H$ is normal in $G$ but $K=<(1,2)>\times 1$
is not normal in $G$ and $K\cap H =K$.

Comment: could you give me some other example please, because I'm not familiar with $\times$.

Comment: @Franklin: Set $G=S_4$ and $H=A_4$ and $K$ be a subgroup of order $3$ again $K\cap H=K$ but $K$ is not normal in $G$.